# Enumerable.Unit() function

Tags: c#, ienumerable

Finding myself in the situation where I have a method with this signature

```
void DoSomething(IEnumerable<T> before, IEnumerable<T> after)
```

I find myself often having to call it when I've just got one element and not IEnumerable.

I thought of adding the three overloads, but that doesn't help when one of the arguments is null.

So I thought I could just 'wrap up' my single element in an IEnumerable and send it on, but I can't find anything on Enumerable which looks like what I want (maybe I'm not looking hard enough).

So I'm looking at something like this

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> EnumerableUnit<T>(T item)
    {
        if(item != null) yield return item;
    }
```

Is this a good idea? Or is there something better I should be doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might help:

```
new[]{obj}
```

Comment: Yup, that's definitely better (well, looks better to me) than the new List<T>(obj), which I had thought of.

Comment: `new List<T>(obj)` requires writing down the type explicitly. Don't worry about `new`ing an array too much. If there were an `Enumerable.Unit<T>(obj)`, it would have had to instantiate a new class to return anyway.

Comment: Ah. I hate inconsistent markdown interpretation in comments vs. posts.